# Contiguous Subarray Max

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve the contiguous subarray problem on CodeSignal & I came up with the following solution which is based off of Kadane's Algorithm. *My implementation passed the given test data set however upon submission, it failed.* There's no reason given on CodeSignal & I can't look at it since I just started doing it & have less coins.

*I can't figure out why my solution is failing but the solution based on online pseudo code works*, even though my solution passed the preliminary tests. I think it might have to do with integer overflow or some other reason *that's why I've come here to seek help from experts.*

My implementation:

```
 public int findConsecutiveSubarray(int nums[]) {
    int currentSum = 0;
    int max =Integer.MIN_VALUE;;

    int i=0;
    while(i < nums.length) {
        currentSum += nums[i];

        if(max < currentSum)
            max = currentSum;

        if(max < nums[i]) {
            max = nums[i];
            currentSum = nums[i];
        }

        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("maxSum : "+ max);
    return max;
}
```

Solution based on online:

```
int arrayMaxConsecutiveSum2(int[] nums) {
        int currentMax = 0;
        int globalMax = 0;
        
        globalMax = currentMax = nums[0];
        
        for(int i=1; i<nums.length; i++) {
            currentMax = Math.max(nums[i], currentMax + nums[i]);
            globalMax = Math.max(globalMax, currentMax);
        }
    
    return globalMax;
}
```

Comment: what is the precise definition of the question?

Comment: Coding questions and requests for help with your code are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you might not enter the second "if" when the current sum is smaller than `nums[i]`.
Imagine, e.g., that at the beginning of the iteration you have  `currentSum=-5`, `max=100`, `nums[i]=10`.
At the end of the iteration you have `currentSum=5` and `max=100`, yet the desired state is `currentSum=10`, `max=100`.

A corresponding instance where your algorithm fails is: `100, -105, 10, 95`.

To fix this, the condition of the second "if" should be `currentSum < nums[i]`.

Notice that, once you change this condition, you'll also have to revise other parts of your code accordingly: you can no longer unconditionally assign `max` to `nums[i]` in the body of the second "if" statement. This can be easily fixed by removing that assignment and swapping the order of your two ifs.

```
[...]
        if(currentSum < nums[i])
            currentSum = nums[i];

        if(max < currentSum)
            max = currentSum;        
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Really appreciate it! One more question, how did you find out this problem & come up with a dataset as well? I'd like to learn this so in future, I can find such loop holes myself.

Comment: The problem is a classic problem in computer science. See [Maximum Subarray Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) on Wikipedia. I didn't come up with a dataset, I just read your code.